# Symmetrization and antisymmetrization of multilinear transformations

Tags: real-analysis, multilinear-algebra

Let $\beta: \Bbb R^n \times \dots \times \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ be $r$-linear. Define

$$ \operatorname{symm}(\beta)(v_{1},\dots,v_{r}) = \frac{1}{r!} \sum_{\pi}^{}\beta(v_{\pi(1)},\dots,v_{\pi(r)})$$
where $\pi$ ranges through the set of permutations of {1,..,r}, and
define the antisymmetrization$$ \operatorname{asymm}(\beta)(v_{1},\dots,v_{r}) = \frac{1}{r!} \sum_{\pi}^{} \operatorname{sgn}(\pi) 
\beta(v_{\pi(1)},\dots,v_{\pi(r)}) $$
I'm hoping to prove $ \alpha = \beta - \operatorname{symm}(\beta) $ is antisymmetric in the sense that for any permutation $\pi$ over $\{1,...,r\}$, $\alpha(v_{\pi(1)},\dots,v_{\pi(r)}) = \operatorname{sgn}(\pi)\alpha(v_{1},\dots,v_{r})$.

I have proved that

i) $\operatorname{symm}(\beta)$ is symmetric, and $\operatorname{symm}(\beta)=\beta \iff \beta$ is symmetric

ii)$\operatorname{asymm}(\beta)$ is antisymmetric, and $\operatorname{asymm}(\beta)=\beta \iff \beta$ is antisymmetric

thus to prove $\alpha$ is antisymmetric, we can instead show $\operatorname{asymm}(\alpha) = \alpha$:
$$\operatorname{asymm}(\alpha) = \operatorname{asymm}(\beta - \operatorname{symm}(\beta)) = \operatorname{asymm}(\beta)$$
as $\operatorname{asymm}(\operatorname{symm}(\beta))=0$.
However, I'm having trouble showing $\operatorname{asymm}(\beta) = \alpha, $ or $ \operatorname{asymm}(\beta) + \operatorname{symm}(\beta) = \beta $
$$\begin{split}\operatorname{asymm}(\beta)+\operatorname{symm}(\beta)(v_{1},\dots,v_{r}) &= \frac{1}{r!} \sum_{\pi}^{} \operatorname{sgn}(\pi) 
\beta(v_{\pi(1)},\dots,v_{\pi(r)})+\frac{1}{r!} \sum_{\pi}^{}\beta(v_{\pi(1)},\dots,v_{\pi(r)})\\
&= \frac{2}{r!}\sum_{\pi 
  \text{ even}}^{}\beta(v_{\pi(1)},\dots,v_{\pi(r)})\end{split}$$
I don't see why this would equal to $\beta(v_{1},\dots,v_{r})$.

Any hints on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: It's not always true for $r>2$. I encourage you to look for a counterexample when $r=3$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! For expressions which might wander off the page entirely, you should try to use the `\begin{split} \end{split}` syntax. But it is a bit refreshing to see a well-written first question. Otherwise, have a nice day.